# QueryBuilder still returning Entity after delete

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I have a listview with an adapter with a list of entities loaded using QueryBuilder.list().
When a delete a entites from this list ( mylist.remove(entiy) and then mydao.delete(entity)) and performing an new request using QueryBuilder.list() my entity is still there.

I suppose that it is related to the cache so i tried first to clear my daosession and also to use a lazylist (uncached). But it is not working.

I dont know where to look next !

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you post some code? I believe sth else is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in the project i am working on, there is a thread which was loading the entities, call a webservices to fill some data and then update the entities, so they were updated again even if i was deleting them from my activity with the list view.

But i found weird that i can perform an update on a deleted entities. It would have been better to have a exception.